# Java selectionChange Listener for combo box

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, listener

I have this combo box that I would like to enable or disable depending on a selection of "SDO/OD", (coded as 10 in database) in a previous combo box.  When I use the following code it gives me the drop down listing, but for every choice.  I want the drop down for only when "SDO/OD" is chosen.  Otherwise, disable the combo box but allow the data to pass the null for the record.  I don't think it is reading the Listener.  My question is why is this happening?  How to I handle the Listerner to accommodate such a task?

```
fcbRole.addSelectionChangedListener(new SelectionChangedListener<ModelData>()
    {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<ModelData> se) 
        {
            fcbOfficeRegion.clearSelections();
            fcbOfficeRegion.getStore().clearFilters();

            if(fcbRole.getValue().equals("SDO/OD") && se.getSelectedItem() != null)
            {
                fcbOfficeRegion.enable();
                fcbOfficeRegion.setValueField(se.getSelectedItem().get("strValue").toString());
                StoreFilter<ModelData> sfRole = new StoreFilter<ModelData>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean select(Store<ModelData> store,
                            ModelData parent, ModelData item,
                            String property) {
                        String name = item.get("filterDepts");  
                          name = getScc().cleanString(name.toLowerCase());   
                          if (name.contains("(" + fcbRole.getValue().get("strValue") + ")")) 
                          {  

                            return true;  
                          }  
                        return false;

                    }
                };

                fcbOfficeRegion.getStore().addFilter(sfRole); 
                fcbOfficeRegion.getStore().applyFilters("fcbOfficeRegion");
            }
            else
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you trying to enable/disable the combo box based on the user selection of that combo box?

Answer (score 3):

Best of [Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) for  [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) is [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html), this `Listener` fired events `SELECTED/DESELECTED`, always twice

Comment: How would that look?  I don't think the code I am working with is of  JComboBox type.  When I add the suggestion it gives back error when I replace the Listener.